# Abort trap: 6 (Calculating a long number factorial)

Tags: c, factorial

I am following the following function to calculate factorials of big numbers [link](http://www.cquestions.com/2010/08/factorial-of-big-numbers-in-c.html), and I would like to understand a bit more why some things are happening...

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define MAX 10000
void factorialof(int);
void multiply(int);
int length = 0;
int fact[MAX];

int main(){
    int num;
    int i;

    printf("Enter any integer number : ");
    scanf("%d",&num);
   
    fact[0]=1;

    factorialof(num);
   
    printf("Factorial is : ");
    for(i=length;i>=0;i--){
         printf("%d",fact[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}

void factorialof(int num){
    int i;
    for(i=2;i<=num;i++){
         multiply(i);
    }
}
void multiply(int num){
    long i,r=0;
    int arr[MAX];
    for(i=0;i<=length;i++){
                arr[i]=fact[i];
        }

    for(i=0;i<=length;i++){
         fact[i] = (arr[i]*num + r)%10;
         r = (arr[i]*num + r)/10;
         //printf("%d ",r);
    }
    if(r!=0){
         while(r!=0){
             fact[i]=r%10;
             r= r/10;
             i++;
         }
    }
    length = i-1;   
}
```

My questions are:

1. What is the real meaning of the MAX constant? What does it mean if it's bigger or smaller?
2. I have found out that if I have a MAX = 10000 (as in the example), I can calculate up to 3250! If I try with 3251! I get a 'Abort trap: 6' message. Why is that number? Where does it come from?
3. Which would be the difference if I compile this code for a 32-bit machine with the flag -m32? Would it run he same as in 64-bit?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Scott Hunter points out, `MAX` is the maximum number of elements in the `fact` and `arr` arrays, which means it's the maximum number of digits that can occur in the result before the program runs out of space.

Note that the code only uses `MAX` in its array declarations. Nowhere does it use `MAX` to determine whether or not it's trying to read from or write to memory beyond the end of those arrays. This is a Bad Thing™. Your "Abort trap: 6" error is almost certainly occurring because trying to compute 3251! is doing exactly that: using a too-large index with `arr` and `fact`.

To see the number of digits required for a given factorial, you can increase `MAX` (say, to 20,000) and replace the existing `printf` calls in `main` with something like this:

```
printf("Factorial requires %d digits.\n", length + 1);
```

Note that I use `length + 1` because `length` isn't the number of digits by itself: rather, it's the index of the array position in `fact` that contains the most-significant digit of the result. If I try to compute 3251!, the output is:

```
Factorial requires 10008 digits.
```

This is eight digits more than you have available in `fact` with the default `MAX` value of 10,000. Once the program logic goes beyond the allocated space in the array, its behavior is undefined. You happen to be seeing the error "Abort trap: 6."

Interestingly, here's the output when I try to compute 3250!:

```
Factorial requires 10005 digits.
```

That's still too many for the program to behave reliably when `MAX` is set to 10,000, so the fact that your program calculates 3250! successfully might be surprising, but that's the nature of undefined behavior: maybe your program will produce the correct result, maybe it will crash, maybe it will become self-aware and launch its missiles against the targets in Russia ([because it knows that the Russian counterattack will eliminate its enemies over here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4DQsG3TKQ0I)). Coding like this is not a good idea. If your program requires more space than it has available in order to complete the calculation, it should stop and display an appropriate error message rather than trying to continue what it's doing.

Comment: Great answer! Thanks. So, now I wonder which would be a 'good implementation' to avoid the "Abort trap". How can I know, before calculating the factorial, how many digits will it take? So as to avoid processing a number that would give me an error...

Comment: The easiest approach would be to put some bounds checking into the `multiply` function since that's where all your array writes are. At the very beginning of the function, if `length >= MAX`, then you have a problem, and at the top of the `while` loop, if `i >= MAX`, then you have a problem. You could indicate a problem by, for instance, having the function return a `bool` rather than `void`, indicating whether or not the calculation succeeded.

Comment: Other options would be to use a data structure that can grow as more space is needed rather than a fixed-length array, or to write some input validation that informs the user immediately if he/she enters a value that's too high. (You'd have to either compute the appropriate limit yourself and include it as another constant or derive some function f(n) that yields the number of decimal digits in n!.)

Comment: What about using Stirling's formula?

Answer (score 0):

1. MAX is the number of elements in `fact` and `arr`; trying to access an element with an index >= MAX would be bad.
2. Error messages are often specific to the environment you are using, which you have provided no details for.
3. They are not the same, but the differences (for example, the size of pointers) should not affect this code in any discernible way.